# Кнопка со скошенными углами на React Native

Tags: javascript, button, react-native, border

Подскажите, как сделать кнопку вот с такими скошенными углами в React Native, желательно без псевдоэлементов before и after

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется - это просто картинка

Comment: Нет, это не картинка, это должна быть кнопка TouchableOpacity

Comment: А разве если будет картинка этот эффект будет неприменим? Я имею ввиду, что это кнопка с картинкой

Comment: @Jostar , можете внутрь кнопки поставить блок с position absolute и transform skewX примерно 335deg. Таким образом вы получите внутри кнопки параллелепипед, только не забудьте перекрасить его в другой цвет

Comment: А что из этого должно быть картинкой? При клике менять фон с обычного синего на картинку темной трапеции? Я тебя не понимаю, при чем тут вообще картинка?

Comment: @HTO HOT Спасибо, хорошая идея, не знал про такое свойство. Можете вынести в отдельный ответ? Отмечу галочкой

Comment: @Jostar , стандартное св-во css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можете внутрь кнопки поставить блок с `position absolute` и `transform skewX` примерно `335deg`. Таким образом вы получите внутри кнопки параллелепипед, только не забудьте перекрасить его в другой цвет.